# Is there any way to disable WordPad's Text-Only format save warning?

Tags: wordpad, dialog, ux

Is there any way to disable the following warning from [Microsoft] WordPad?

[image: Wordpad warning: "You are about to save the document in a Text-Only format, which will remove all formatting. Are you sure you want to do this? To save in other format, click No."].

Yes, I know I'm saving this document as a text-only .txt file.  I've already said Yes to this dialog 25 times since opening this document, after each update.  Can I turn this warning off, *in WordPad* (i.e. without just switching to a different text editor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saying Yes to save the document, close and reopen it.
Then, don't paste in formatted text, and the warning won't keep coming up.

Answer (score 0):

WordPad is a word processor, like a more basic version of Microsoft Word.  It is giving you this warning as you are not using WordPad in the way it was mainly designed to be used.

If what you want to do is create raw text files with no formatting, a text editor is what you would want to use instead.

[There are many to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_editors) (hundreds), but popular ones for Windows that you may want to look into are [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) (a big improvement on the standard Notepad editor in Windows) and Notepad++ (fully featured and expandable).

Answer (score 0):

Neither answer above worked for me. So I copied all from the existing file. Next I opened a brand new, empty WordPad. Then I clicked Paste > Paste Special > Unformatted Text. Saved this as a new file. This got rid of the annoying error message!